# Deploy Neo4j on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I've been developing my rails application using the gem neo4j.
When I run the server it executes an embedded neo4j server.

In production, is it ok to use this embedded server?
How can I can connect my rails application with with the standalone neo4j server?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly normal to deploy in production using the embedded server. Maybe it's even easier then using the standalone server. Why do you want to connect your rails application to a standalone neo4j server ? This is normally not needed, but could be nice as a development tool to visualize the graph using the server admin UI (there is also the neo4j-admin gem for this).

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to maintain app and db server independently. How can we deploy a standalone Neo4J server and connect it to a rails app as one might do with a dedicated MySQL server?

Comment: More information in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4jrb/VP3bokTedjk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can use the gem [neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) to achieve this. Just set it up with the ip of your standalone server and you should be good to go.